# Jenkins join trigger either not triggering downstream projects, or triggering twice

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have the following setup.

JobA = some base dependencies. When that's compiled, I want to kick off both JobB and JobC.
When both JobB and JobC are complete I had a join trigger for JobD - to prevent JobE or JobF from kicking off when JobB or JobC complete.

The problem I have is that JobE or JobF kick off when either JobB or JobC complete.
Is this something which the join trigger plugin can achieve?

```
    A

 B     C

    D

 E     F
```

JobA is triggered by remote github pushes. 
JobA has a post-build action to build JobB and JobC, and JobA also has a Join Trigger pointing at JobD

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot, I forgot I had left something in which dicking around.
JobB and JobC were both configured to trigger JobD after a successful build, thus completely working against the join trigger.

DOH!